# pass batch size in deleteByQuery [elasticsearch] [scala]

Tags: scala, elasticsearch, nosql, elastic-stack, elastic4s

I need to pass batch size while using deletebyQuery.

My requirement is:

- Get x rows based on filters
- Run DeletebyQuery on them
- Return this list

While doing search using filters, there can 1000 rows but I need only batch of top 100. Need to return these 100 rows and run deleteByQuery, only on these 100.

What is the way to do this?

Here is the code of what I tried, but it ended up deleting all 1000 rows.

```
val searchQuery =
  search(Index.name)
  .size(100)
    .query(boolQuery.should(
      termQuery(Type.status, Type.state)))

 getElasticsearchClient().execute(searchQuery)

 val result = elasticsearchClient().execute (
    deleteByQuery(Index.name, Index.typeName,
      boolQuery.should(termQuery(Type.status, Type.state))).size(100))
```

Answer (score 2):

Since 7.3, the delete-by-query endpoint supports a [`max_docs` parameter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-delete-by-query.html#docs-delete-by-query-api-query-params) that you can use (formerly it was called `size`).

I'm not sure which version you are using, but elastic4s, the `DeleteByQueryRequest` constructor provides a [`size` parameter](https://github.com/sksamuel/elastic4s/blob/12b9729279c8d72fb8cce5b7952ff436f3891ec1/elastic4s-core/src/main/scala/com/sksamuel/elastic4s/requests/delete/DeleteByQueryRequest.scala#L22) which you can use.

Comment: I did use .size(100). Am I using it wrong? Bcoz this does not work. We are not on 7.3 so size parameter should work.

Comment: That's the point, from 7.3 on, the parameter is called `max_docs` and it doesn't look like the deleteByQuery implementation supports it.

Comment: Yes, I dont see `max_docs` in autocomplete. So, there is no other way to pass a very specific batch size then.

Comment: The thing is that `size` should still be supported until 8... I'll investigate deeper

Comment: Ya. Size does not seem to be working. It ends up deleting more than the batch. Please update if u find more details.

Comment: Checking up if some reason was found for size not working?

Comment: According to [this issue](https://github.com/sksamuel/elastic4s/issues/1375), it's supposed to be fixed in version 7.0.1 of elastic4s. Which version are you running?

Comment: We are on 6.1.3. So, it makes sense why this is not working. Thanks Val for the details.

Comment: anything else needed to close this question?